# Mark as Read loop errors on some mail items inconsistently

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive 4000+ emails over a weekend and all throughout the week that are filtered into folders via rules. I created a macro to mark all these folders as read. However, on some mail items it errors with `runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set`.

If I skip the errors with `On Error Resume Next` it loops through everything but just doesn't set a bunch of the mail items as read. I can then rerurn the macro to get most of the remaining ones. If I run the macro 3-4 times it will eventually get them all.

How can I improve this macro to consistently mark ALL the items as read?

```
Public Function GetInboxFolderID(FolderName As String) As String
    Dim nsp As Outlook.Folder
    Dim mpfSubFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim mpfSubFolder2 As Outlook.Folder
    Dim flds As Outlook.Folders
    Dim flds2 As Outlook.Folders

    Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set flds = nsp.Folders
    Set mpfSubFolder = flds.GetFirst
    Do While Not mpfSubFolder Is Nothing
        If mpfSubFolder.Name = FolderName Then
            GetInboxFolderID = mpfSubFolder.EntryID
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set flds2 = mpfSubFolder.Folders
        Set mpfSubFolder2 = flds2.GetFirst
        Do While Not mpfSubFolder2 Is Nothing
            If mpfSubFolder2.Name = FolderName Then
                GetInboxFolderID = mpfSubFolder2.EntryID
                Exit Function
            End If
            Set mpfSubFolder2 = flds2.GetNext
        Loop
        Set mpfSubFolder = flds.GetNext
    Loop
End Function

Private Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim oFiltered As Outlook.Items

        Set oFiltered = oParent.Items.Restrict("[unread] = true")
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each oMail In oFiltered

            oMail.UnRead = False

        Next

        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
                processFolder oFolder
            Next
        End If
End Sub

Public Sub markNocAsRead()
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Set SubFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Parent.Folders("NOC Alerts")
    'Application.Session.GetFolderFromID (GetInboxFolderID("NOC Alerts"))
    Call processFolder(SubFolder)
End Sub
```

Comment: Check the oMail.Class of the items that are failing. Class 43 is a 'regular' mail item. You may be getting unexpected mail items (e.g. appointments or something different) that don't have a property you are trying to use.

Comment: I thought about that, but these are all regular mail items. Also, the ones that fail will set just fine on a 2nd or 3rd run of the macro, so they DO have the properties. I'm thinking it may have to do with "loading" the mail item as it can't view the properties until it's properly loaded? I'm not sure.

Comment: If you suspect that, you could looping from the end and working backward. E.g. Get the count of items, and using Step -1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working consistently by taking the advice of Ryan Wildry in a comment above.

I replaced my loop:

```
Set oFiltered = oParent.Items.Restrict("[unread] = true")
On Error Resume Next
For Each oMail In oFiltered
    oMail.UnRead = False
Next
```

with a loop that iterates from the end to beginning:

```
Set oFiltered = oParent.Items.Restrict("[unread] = true")
For I = oFiltered.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set oMail = oFiltered(I)
    oMail.UnRead = False
Next
```